# UIButton unknown shadow appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I change UIButton state from default to selected unknown shadow is appeared to the top left of the button background image. Please tell me how to get rid of it.

```
- (IBAction)pressTestSwitch:(id)sender {
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
     button.selected = !button.selected; 
}
```

[image: default state]

[image: selected state]

Comment: Is that a UIButton - doesn't look like one ?

Comment: This is not enough..Add some more code or information on how you set up the image and the how the image change works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am setting images in storyboard for each button state (default, selected). My problem was in button type. It was 'system' by default. When I've changed it to 'custom', shadow has disappeared. Thanks for helping.